# How to pass Facebook omniauth token to koala in another controller within a ruby app?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, omniauth, koala-gem

i am new to ruby environment.

**In my ruby app, i am authenticating the user using omniauth and i am able to save the facebook token for the logged in user and the problem is i want to pass this token information as parameter to koala which resides in some other controller?**

> How to do it? Kindly help.

**MY OMNIAUTH CONTROLLER:**

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
     @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
     ...
  end
```

**User.rb**

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
  data = access_token.extra.raw_info
  token = access_token.credentials.token //i want to pass this to invite controller

  cookies[:myKey] = token

  if user = self.where(:email => data.email).first
    if(!user.facebook_id)
      if(user.sign_in_count != 0)
        user.facebook_id = data.id 
        user.token = access_token
        user.save
      else
        user.destroy
        user = User.new(:name=>(data.name).split(" ")[0], :email => data.email, :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20], :provider => "facebook", :facebook_id => data.id)
        user.skip_confirmation!
        user.save!
      end
    end
  user
  else # Create a user with a stub password. 
  user = User.new(:name=>(data.name).split(" ")[0], :email => data.email, :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20], :provider => "facebook", :facebook_id => data.id)
  user.skip_confirmation!
  user.save!
  user
  end

end
```

**MY INVITE CONTROLLER** *(where i am trying to fetch facebook user data using koala gem)*

```
class InviteController < ApplicationController

def invite
fb ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(cookies[:myKey])
     @friends = fb.get_connections("me", "friends")
  render json: @friends
 end
end
```

Comment: Where your code from and what is not going well?

Comment: Why can't you just store token in database and use it whenever you need?

Comment: Thanks @Icicle now i am storing the token in database. It's working fine now! Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

**Now i am storing the token in database. It's working fine now! Thanks all.**